# Join differently sized dataframes on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of item sales, and a smaller one of costs for each item, called `june_2008` and `costs_2008`. I need to join them so that each of many sales has its price nex to it, so I can get things like profit margins.

[image]

[image]

The intent is to match them on the `SKU` index. I've tried with/without the index.

I've been trying merge and join commands in pandas, but don't know the specific details and can't get them joined as needed. Can you show how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you provided a minimal code example instead of screenshots. If the tables are indexed like your example above, it may be as easy as `june_2008['Unit Cost 2008'] = costs_2008['Unit Cost 2008']`

Comment: Please show dataframe as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the "SKU" is an index, I recommend you create a column called "SKU" using reset_index command, like this:

```
june_2008.reset_index(inplace=True)
costs_2008.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

After that, a simple merge should resolve your problem:

```
pd.merge(june_2008, costs_2008, on=["SKU"])
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the "SKU" columns were different datatypes. Once they're made identical a merge command is simple.